# linear transformations Finding $T(v_1) - T(v_3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Question:

[image]

Solution:

[image]

I get 3) a

but I don't get 3 b,

how are they getting these numbers? im stumped

Comment: How can anyone answer if you don't tell us what are the basis?

Comment: Sorry~ forgot my bad

Comment: Please take the time to enter the core of your question as text instead of simply pasting images. The latter are neither searchable nor accessible to people using screen readers. You can find a tutorial for formatting mathematical expressions in MathJax [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned}
T(v_1)&=1\cdot v_1 + 2\cdot v_2 + 6\cdot v_3\\
&=3x+3x^2+2(-1+3x+2x^2)+6(3+7x+2x^2)\\
&=16+51x+19x^2
\end{aligned}$$
The other two are similar.